# Dict Deconstruction and Reconstruction in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries. There is a great deal of overlap between the dictionaries, but they are not identical.

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
b = {'a':1,'c':3, 'd':4}
c = {'a':1,'c':3}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to break these down into the most primitive pieces and then reconstruct the dictionaries in the most efficient manner. In other words, how can I deconstruct and rebuild the dictionaries by typing each key/value pair the minimum number of times (ideally once). It also means creating the minimum number of sets that can be combined to create all possible sets that exist.

In the above example. It could be broken down into:

```
c = {'a':1,'c':3}
a = dict(c.items() + {'b':2})
b = dict(c.items() + {'d':4})
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach this in Python.

In reality, I have roughly 60 dictionaries and many of them have overlapping values. I'm trying to minimize the number of times I have to type each k/v pair to minimize potential typo errors and make it easier to cascade update different values for specific keys.

An ideal output would be the most basic dictionaries needed to construct all dictionaries as well as the formula for reconstruction.

Comment: fixed the typo. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: We need a more precise problem statement. What makes a piece "most primitive"? What's your metric of efficiency? What operations are we allowed to use in this breakdown and reconstruction, and what constraints are we working under?

Comment: what is 'the most efficient manner'?

Comment: Most effiencient means typing each key/value pair the least number of times, ideally once each.

Comment: Build sets using (key, value) tuples for each dict, and take the intersection of all.

Comment: so 'most efficient' in your terminology would be `{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}, {'d':4}`. Probably you also want to use only the sets you have as initial ones?

Comment: No quite. since {'a':1} always occurs with {'c':3}, there is no need to keep the separate. I guess efficient also means the least number of underlying dictionaries as well.

Comment: so you also want a minimum possible number of sets (which you didn't mention)

Comment: Yes. minimum number of sets to create all possible sets that exists.

Comment: Do equal keys always have equal numbers? In this case, I suggest rewording the problem to use sets instead of dicts. I'm pretty sure that this is a well known problem for sets, but can't pin it down right now...

Comment: Yeah, I originally had it listed as sets, but changed it to be more specific to my actual problem. 

I know there has to be this problem for sets too, but don't know what to search for because I can't think of the name.

Comment: I can't be the only one that's totally lost as to what this question is proposing doing. What's your expected output with what you've got there? Starting with a, b, and c, what's the output of `function_that_does_exactly_what_you_want(a, b, c)`?

Comment: In your exemple the dics are nested. is it always the case ? if yes it seems simple.

Comment: it's an interesting problem, just to give you a directions,you should probably start here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Related_problems

Comment: `ds=(a,b,c); dmin = min(ds, key=len); [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if k not in d    min} for x in ds if x is not dmin]` produces `[{'b': 2}, {'d': 4}]` (`dmin` contains the base for building them, i..e the most primitive dict). I prefer to post it as a comment since I am unsure I understand the problem in full. If it works in all the cases you have in mind, not just the given example, I will post it as an answer

Comment: What is the point of doing this? Do you just want to merge the dicts? Just overwrite the keys. If two dicts have different values for the same keys, make your values lists and append there.

Comment: @Pynchia I think this is getting to what I'm looking for. Going to try on a larger scale and see how it works.

Comment: @RomanPekar this is the general problem I'm trying to solve. Going to spend time looking for answers related to Optimal set cover

Comment: just to clarify, what will be the answer for `a = {'a','b','c'}, b = {'a','c','d'}, c = {'a','c'}, d = {'a','b'}`?

Comment: @Bradley you say "**many** of them (the dictionaries) have overlapping values". The assumption at the base of my solution is **all** of them have overlapping values, i.e. all the dictionaries intersect. Otherwise there wouldn't be a common/core building block

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It isn't the most efficient in any way, but it might give you an idea of how to proceed.

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
b = {'a':1,'c':3, 'd':4}
c = {'a':1,'c':3}

class Cover:
    def __init__(self,*dicts):
        # Our internal representation is a link to any complete subsets, and then a dictionary of remaining elements
        mtx = [[-1,{}] for d in dicts]
        for i,dct in enumerate(dicts):
            for j,odct in enumerate(dicts):
                if i == j: continue # we're always a subset of ourself
                # if everybody in A is in B, create the reference
                if all( k in dct for k in odct.keys() ):
                    mtx[i][0] = j
                    dif = {key:value for key,value in dct.items() if key not in odct}
                    mtx[i][1].update(dif)
                    break 

        for i,m in enumerate(mtx):
            if m[1] == {}: m[1] = dict(dicts[i].items())

        self.mtx = mtx

    def get(self, i):
        r = { key:val for key, val in self.mtx[i][1].items()} 
        if (self.mtx[i][0] > 0): # if we had found a subset, add that
            r.update(self.mtx[self.mtx[i][0]][1])
        return r


cover = Cover(a,b,c) 

print(a,b,c)
print('representation',cover.mtx)
# prints [[2, {'b': 2}], [2, {'d': 4}], [-1, {'a': 1, 'c': 3}]]
# The "-1" In the third element indicates this is a building block that cannot be reduced; the "2"s indicate that these should build from the 2th element 
print('a',cover.get(0)) 
print('b',cover.get(1))
print('c',cover.get(2))
```

The idea is very simple: if any of the maps are complete subsets, substitute the duplication for a reference. The compression could certainly backfire for certain matrix combinations, and can be easily improved upon

**Simple improvements**

Change the first line of get, or using your more concise dictionary addition code hinted at in the question, might immediately improve readability.

We don't check for the *largest* subset, which may be worthwhile.

The implementation is naive and makes no optimizations

**Larger improvements**

One could also implement a hierarchical implementation in which "building block" dictionaries formed the root nodes and the tree was descended to build the larger dictionaries. This would only be beneficial if your data was hierarchical to start.

(Note: tested in python3)

Answer (score 0):

Below a script to generate a script that reconstruct dictionaries.

For example consider this dictionary of  dictionaries:

```
>>>dicts
{'d2': {'k4': 'k4', 'k1': 'k1'},
 'd0': {'k2': 'k2', 'k4': 'k4', 'k1': 'k1', 'k3': 'k3'},
 'd4': {'k4': 'k4', 'k0': 'k0', 'k1': 'k1'},
 'd3': {'k0': 'k0', 'k1': 'k1'},
 'd1': {'k2': 'k2', 'k4': 'k4'}}
```

For clarity, we continue with sets because the association key value can be done elsewhere.

```
sets= {k:set(v.keys()) for k,v in dicts.items()} 

>>>sets
{'d2': {'k1', 'k4'},
 'd0': {'k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'},
 'd4': {'k0', 'k1', 'k4'},
 'd3': {'k0', 'k1'},
 'd1': {'k2', 'k4'}}
```

Now compute the distances (number of keys to add or/and  remove to go from one dict to another):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dicts)
charfunc=df.notnull()
distances=pd.DataFrame((charfunc.values.T[...,None] != charfunc.values).sum(1),
                       df.columns,df.columns)

>>>>distances 
    d0  d1  d2  d3  d4
d0   0   2   2   4   3
d1   2   0   2   4   3
d2   2   2   0   2   1
d3   4   4   2   0   1
d4   3   3   1   1   0
```

Then the script that write the script. The idea is to begin with the shortest set, and then at each step to construct the nearest set from those already built:

```
script=open('script.py','w')
dicoto=df.count().argmin() # the shortest set
script.write('res={}\nres['+repr(dicoto)+']='+str(sets[dicoto])+'\ns=[\n')
done=[]
todo=df.columns.tolist()
while True :
    done.append(dicoto)
    todo.remove(dicoto)
    if not todo : break
    table=distances.loc[todo,done]
    ito,ifrom=np.unravel_index(table.values.argmin(),table.shape)
    dicofrom=table.columns[ifrom]
    setfrom=sets[dicofrom]
    dicoto=table.index[ito]
    setto=sets[dicoto]
    toadd=setto-setfrom
    toremove=setfrom-setto
    script.write(('('+repr(dicoto)+','+str(toadd)+','+str(toremove)+','
    +repr(dicofrom)+'),\n').replace('set',''))
script.write("""]
for dt,ta,tr,df in s:
    d=res[df].copy()
    d.update(ta)
    for k in tr: d.remove(k)
    res[dt]=d
""")    
script.close()
```

and the produced file `script.py`

```
res={}
res['d1']={'k2', 'k4'}
s=[
('d0',{'k1', 'k3'},(),'d1'),
('d2',{'k1'},{'k2'},'d1'),
('d4',{'k0'},(),'d2'),
('d3',(),{'k4'},'d4'),
]
for dt,ta,tr,df in s:
    d=res[df].copy()
    d.update(ta)
    for k in tr: d.remove(k)
    res[dt]=d
```

Test :

```
>>> %run script.py
>>> res==sets
True
```

With random dicts like here, script size is about 80% of sets size for big dicts (`Nd=Nk=100`) . But for big overlap, the ratio would certainly be better.

Complement : a script to generate such dicts .

```
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
Nd=5 # number of dicts
Nk=5 # number of keys per dict
index=['k'+str(j) for j in range(Nk)]
columns=['d'+str(i) for i in range(Nd)]
charfunc=pd.DataFrame(randint(0,2,(Nk,Nd)).astype(bool),index=index,columns=columns)
dicts={i : { j:j for j in charfunc.index if charfunc.ix[j,i]} for i in charfunc.columns}
```

Comment: I change my last post for a more specific answer.